# Bracket exponential functions from output

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have a complicated function `c2[t, n, d1, d2, g,a10, a01, a00]`, which I would like to put into a form:

```
c2[t, n, d1, d2, g, a10, a01, a00]=(1)*Exp[-a1*t]+(2)*Exp[-a2*t]+...,
```

where (1),(2),... are some prefactors and do not include any exponential functions of time.

The function is enough complicated that it is hard/impossible to see which or how many a1, a2, ... are needed.

I have tried to apply Expand and then by looking to pick the exponential function, and with Coefficients to find (1),..., but it simply takes to long time and is error-prone.

Can I do this quicker?

My function is:

```
 c2[t_, n_, d1_, d2_, g_, a10_, a01_,a00_] = (1 - a00)^2 + a00^2 + 
 2 a01 a10 + (1 + 2 a01 a10 E^(-g (1 + 2 n) t) + (
    4 (-(1 - a00) E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) - (1 - a00) n - 
       a00 n - (1 - a00) E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) n + 
       a00 E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) n))/(1 + 2 n) + (
    2 (-(1 - a00) E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) - (1 - a00) n - 
       a00 n - (1 - a00) E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) n + 
       a00 E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) n)^2)/(1 + 2 n)^2) (-((
     2 a00 n (1 + 2 n))/(1 + 2 n (1 + n))) + (2 a00^2 n (1 + 2 n))/(
    1 + 2 n (1 + n)) + ((1 + 2 a01 a10) n (1 + 2 n))/(
    1 + 2 n (1 + n)) + (
    E^(-((g (1 + 2 n (1 + n)) t)/(
      1 + 2 n))) (-1 - 4 n - 2 n^2) (-1 - 2 n - n^2 - 
       a00^2 (1 + 2 n) - a01 a10 (1 + 2 n) + 2 a00 (1 + 2 n + n^2)))/(
    2 n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n + 2 n^2)) + (1/(
    4 n (1 + n) Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]))
    E^((g (-3 - 6 n - 6 n^2 - Sqrt[
        1 + 4 n + 40 n^2 + 72 n^3 + 36 n^4]) t)/(
     2 (1 + 2 n))) ((1 + n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) - Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       a00^2 (1 + 2 n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) - Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       2 a00 (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (-1 - 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       a01 a10 (1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))] + 
          2 n (1 + n) (3 + 12 n (1 + n) - 
             2 Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]))) + (1/(
    4 n (1 + n) Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]))
    E^((g (-3 - 6 n - 6 n^2 + Sqrt[
        1 + 4 n + 40 n^2 + 72 n^3 + 36 n^4]) t)/(
     2 (1 + 2 n))) (-(1 + n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       2 a00 (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (1 + 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) - 
       a00^2 (1 + 2 n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       a01 a10 (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))] - 
          2 n (1 + n) (3 + 12 n (1 + n) + 
             2 Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))])))) + (-1 + 
    2 a01 a10 E^(-g (1 + 2 n) t) + (
    2 (-(1 - a00) E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) - (1 - a00) n - 
       a00 n - (1 - a00) E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) n + 
       a00 E^(g (-1 - 2 n) t) n)^2)/(1 + 2 n)^2) (-((
     2 a00 (1 + n) (1 + 2 n))/(1 + 2 n (1 + n))) + (
    2 a00^2 (1 + n) (1 + 2 n))/(
    1 + 2 n (1 + n)) + ((1 + 2 a01 a10) (1 + n) (1 + 2 n))/(
    1 + 2 n (1 + n)) + (
    E^(-((g (1 + 2 n (1 + n)) t)/(
      1 + 2 n))) (-1 + 2 n^2) (-1 - 2 n - n^2 - a00^2 (1 + 2 n) - 
       a01 a10 (1 + 2 n) + 2 a00 (1 + 2 n + n^2)))/(
    2 n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n + 2 n^2)) + (1/(
    4 n (1 + n) Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]))
    E^((g (-3 - 6 n - 6 n^2 - Sqrt[
        1 + 4 n + 40 n^2 + 72 n^3 + 36 n^4]) t)/(
     2 (1 + 2 n))) ((1 + n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) - Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       a00^2 (1 + 2 n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) - Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       2 a00 (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (-1 - 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       a01 a10 (1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))] + 
          2 n (1 + n) (3 + 12 n (1 + n) - 
             2 Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]))) + (1/(
    4 n (1 + n) Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]))
    E^((g (-3 - 6 n - 6 n^2 + Sqrt[
        1 + 4 n + 40 n^2 + 72 n^3 + 36 n^4]) t)/(
     2 (1 + 2 n))) (-(1 + n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       2 a00 (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (1 + 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) - 
       a00^2 (1 + 2 n)^2 (1 + 6 n (1 + n) + Sqrt[
          1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))]) + 
       a01 a10 (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))] - 
          2 n (1 + n) (3 + 12 n (1 + n) + 
             2 Sqrt[1 + 4 n (1 + n) (1 + 9 n (1 + n))])))) - 
 2 a01 a10 E^(
  I d2 t - 1/2 g (1 + 2 n) t - (g (1 + 2 n + 2 n^2) t)/(
   2 (1 + 2 n))) (Cos[d1 t] - I Sin[d1 t]) - 
 2 a01 a10 E^(-I d2 t - 1/2 g (1 + 2 n) t - (g (1 + 2 n + 2 n^2) t)/(
   2 (1 + 2 n))) (Cos[d1 t] + I Sin[d1 t])
```

Comment: Does `Collect[expr, Power[E, _], Simplify]` help?

Comment: Yes, this gives the form I was looking for! Many thanks!